# addition of two list elementwise with abortion if condition satisfied python

Tags: python

I have a function that sums two arrays element-wise and stops if the sum at a certain index is greater strictly than 1. This function is called lot of times (15817145 times for a small simulation and expects to grow a lot more as the simulation size grows). Profiling my code shows that it is among the five most consuming functions of my code  and  I believe can be optimized further.

```
def add_lis(lis1, lis2):
    res = []
    for i, j in zip(lis1, lis2):
        if i + j > 1:
            return
        res.append(i + j)
    return array('H', res)
```

`lis1` and `lis2` are both of type `array.array('H',..)`. The two lists have the same length which can be up to 100 and they are both filled with zeroes and ones only. I tried with `numpy` arrays but there is too much overhead that it is not beneficial to use it.

My question is can this function be optimized? Maybe in a sort of list comprehension ?

Comment: You have framed this as a question of speed. But you also say the lists have 100 or fewer elements (ie, tiny) and the function is called several times (meaning unclear, but it also sounds small-scale). Have you benchmarked the code? How much time is this function costing you and is it worth the effort to optimize? Alternatively, perhaps this isn't really a speed issue and you are curious about different ways someone might write this code more clearly or compactly. Perhaps you can edit your question to clarify your goal or at least explain how a substantive speed issue is at play.

Comment: If `lis1` and `lis2` are long, finding the index of the first above-one sum will be fast with numpy, and this function can be vectorized. But you need to show typical calls to this function, and what `lis1` and `lis2` really contain, along with expected lengths.

Comment: hope my edits clear up your questions @FMc

Comment: @sos Yes, indeed, that clears things up. I think the suggestion to try numpy is a good one. It's a library designed to do such things more quickly at a large scale like that -- at least that's my rough understanding of it.

Comment: What's the probability that two lists have a sum larger than 1? What's the probability at each position?

Answer (score 1):

You're operating on individual "bits" with Python code. Can be faster to use data types that do the operations in C. One way is to go `array`→`bytes`→`int`→`bytes`→`array`, doing the operations at the `int` level:

```
def dont_talk_just_code(lis1, lis2):
    b1 = lis1.tobytes()
    b2 = lis2.tobytes()
    i1 = int.from_bytes(b1, 'big')
    i2 = int.from_bytes(b2, 'big')
    if i1 & i2:
        return
    b = (i1 | i2).to_bytes(len(b1), 'big')
    return array('H', b)
```

Benchmark results when there is *no* sum larger than 1:

```
18.77 μs  18.97 μs  19.23 μs  original
19.24 μs  19.39 μs  19.57 μs  _8349697
 1.74 μs   1.74 μs   1.78 μs  dont_talk_just_code
```

Benchmark results where there's a sum larger than 1 at index 50:

```
 7.94 μs   7.98 μs   8.02 μs  original
 2.48 μs   2.48 μs   2.52 μs  _8349697
 1.10 μs   1.11 μs   1.11 μs  dont_talk_just_code
```

Maybe `array`→`bytes`→`numpy`→`bytes`→`array` would be even faster, I didn't try.

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRtjpswEP3PKUZabbFTRIF0t7srpb97hyiyTDBZ74KNjFMpVY/WM/RK6dgmEEq0/gF45vHmzYfdneyrVuunzpzPtdEtWNkKaUG2nTYWjOgEt9Flx1Wl28jjuDH8dIH5TbDXR7W3Wjf9xddxYyVvoqgSNWgjD1LxhjSyzxPAZ0FfIsBlRA8b2O78ptYGZAJvIBX8kt0S7ZasQcJnBH2HfLIGLns0Kpq2fcq7TqiK@B9oNIGCdBL/iBOHo0Eme1p/fX58/rYMjEEJWnL6obQrAcswQcRHOdJBRqWVZZY37@zt2Fu215VYxitzrJuzplaXJyt6EvIri2Av/rNLh5fKpq5dLHhKpIxLeYgHSHEDUswhtSP6hNCbWZdIQBDwGwEUBQwkjVAYi86YlgUqMX03Rm4gLgOTjD1JbpUl1GtvcFgF@8kbWZGhPLyqRIVEYXbT/auWe1SyJVkCGSpxb6fIdTWjuwTeN3mWBWlTrZHA9Wjl2SYnmq90O8voKxa@YpbvxI3J4igwNwco8iDIepA@Cz/PzfvvPGL7kO2GTg@f@XiGXBUdr6/m1Kg76Ay2lzjzbO5GhDq2pTCOK8M1mt3l4LrS48EWFQm3AxlOuKdLrlRjVQPPJrwo3b6sdyNZ0LAi8f1DWtTw908PMdwDsfDlEn8FuXikPhXr8vDxkdZFShlTvBWMBdWBjZ7P/wA)):

```
from timeit import repeat
import random
from array import array
from functools import partial

def original(lis1, lis2):
    res = []
    for i, j in zip(lis1, lis2):
        if i + j > 1:
            return
        res.append(i + j)
    return array('H', res)

def _8349697(lis1, lis2):
    if (1, 1) in zip(lis1, lis2):
        return
    return array('H', (i + j for i, j in zip(lis1, lis2)))

def dont_talk_just_code(lis1, lis2):
    b1 = lis1.tobytes()
    b2 = lis2.tobytes()
    i1 = int.from_bytes(b1, 'big')
    i2 = int.from_bytes(b2, 'big')
    if i1 & i2:
        return
    b = (i1 | i2).to_bytes(len(b1), 'big')
    return array('H', b)

funcs = original, _8349697, dont_talk_just_code

def create_valid():
    added = random.choices([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)], k=100)
    lis1, lis2 = zip(*added)
    lis1 = array('H', lis1)
    lis2 = array('H', lis2)
    return lis1, lis2

for _ in range(3):
    lis1, lis2 = create_valid()
    # lis1[50] = lis2[50] = 1
    for func in funcs:
        # print(func(lis1, lis2))
        number = 10000
        times = sorted(repeat(partial(func, lis1, lis2), number=number))[:3]
        print(*('%5.2f μs ' % (t / number * 1e6) for t in times), func.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: Ugh, just realized this is an old question, only got "bumped" by the stupid "Community Bot". Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

Does it make sense (in the context of your program execution) to split your task into two stages?

Check for the presence of `(1, 1) in zip(lis1, lis2)`, and if `False`, then pass the generator to the array: `array('H', (i + j for i, j in zip(lis1, lis2)))`.